# Selenium WebDriver "find_element_by_xpath" on WebElement

Tags: python, html, find, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to look up an element using the following line:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='Display']")
```

Once i have the elements, which I know there are two of "Display", i want to be able to use the second one and find a specific element inside it, like so:

```
title = elements[1].find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='Title']")
```

However, it always reverts to using the first one.  I've stepped through it, and it is finding 2 elements for "Display", so i'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='Display']")
title = elements[1].find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='Title']")
```

Comment: In java, this would be :  `WebElement myXpathElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("your_xpath"));`.