# Python how to write in triple quotes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, selenium

I really have no idea how to word that title but this is what I'm trying to do
So basically, I'm trying to let the client or user select what class he wants to use but I can't find away to do that because it requires triple quotes

```
from selenium import webdriver

x = str("\"\"\"")
y = str("\"\"\"")
class_name = input("Class name: ")
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094153/selenium-webdriver-find-element-by-xpath-on-webelement")
driver.find_element_by_xpath(x + class_name + y).click()
```

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do with those triple-quotes, but they are only used for literals, which `class_name` is not. And I don't see any `exec` or `eval` there, so that's out too. This is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use [`find_element_by_css_selector`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_css_selector)? To find element with class with xpath require a lot more efforts.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.' + class_name).click()
```

BTW, triple-quote string is not related to the problem.

Comment: Worked, wow I've been trying this for a few hours now, thanks <3, I'll take a look at find_element_by_css_selector

Comment: Alright, got it, Anyway to multiply two functions together? here's what im working with
http://hastebin.com/jitetakuxi.py

Comment: @Ghost, Multiply? Just use one of `find_element_by_css_selector('.' + class_name)` / `find_element_by_class_name(class_name)`. You don't need to use both.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple and use [`find_element_by_class_name()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_class_name) method directly:

```
from selenium import webdriver  

class_name = input("Class name: ")
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094153/selenium-webdriver-find-element-by-xpath-on-webelement")
driver.find_element_by_class_name(class_name).click()
```